# The same algebraic variety defined by different sets of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $\emptyset\neq X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an algebraic variety such that 
$$
X=V(F_{1},\ldots,F_{m})
$$
for certain linearly independent homogeneous polynomials $F_{1},\ldots,F_{m}\in K[X_{0},\ldots,X_{n}]$ of degree $2$.

Let us suppose that $G_{1},\ldots,G_{m}\in K[X_{0},\ldots,X_{n}]$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree $d$ such that 
$$
X= V(G_{1},\ldots,G_{m}).
$$
I would like to prove that $d=2$. Is it true? How could I prove it? In case it is not true, are there easy conditions we should impose for the result to hold?

Comment: Is the equation scheme-theoretic or set theoretic? If set-theoretic, clearly, $X=V(F_1^r,\ldots, F_m^r)$ for any $r>0$.

Comment: Consider a basic case: $V(X_0)$ versus $V(X_0^2)$. The sets are the same.

Comment: @Mohan I think it should be scheme-theoretic then. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you should ask a more precise question. What if I took a basis for all quadrics as my $F_i$? Then $X=\emptyset$ and for any $G_i$s, your hypothesis will work.